# Using user input in VBA code and extracting data into workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am exploring webscraping to try and improve efficiency when inputting data. Unfortunately the website I wish to extract data from is now in  tabular format and so I wish to use VBA to manipulate the website to the desired result.

I'm not very familiar with coding/VBA but so far I have got VBA to open a website and search for a provided value. In this case  the CAS number `67-64-1` refs Acetone on the website.

The code for this is:

```
Sub BrowseToSite()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

IE.Visible = True

IE.Navigate "https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/Search.aspx#"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Loop

IE.Document.forms("form1").elements("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtSearch").Value = "67-64-1"
IE.Document.forms("form1").elements("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnSearch").Click

End Sub
```

Ultimately I wish to create a list in an excel sheet of CAS numbers that this code can loop through and return either the found phrase (in this case `No safety concern at current levels of intake when used as a flavouring agent`) or simply return a "Not Found". Sometimes the search returns multiple results, for the time being I just wish to take the first result.

This raises 2 problems I'm not sure how to solve:

1. How can I modify my code to loop through values within a column of a worksheet instead of having to explicitly give each one.

2.I'm unsure how to pull the data into the adjacent column.

Below is an image of the desired output. Column A is inputted by the user and hopefully column B is created by VBA code.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

what you need is a step by step process for web scraping.

1. i highly recommend you get familiar with seleniumbasic for vba https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/
2. you need to loop on your excel rows using Range() or Cells(i,1) to read the row.
3. you check the number of search results using collections
4. save as many results as you wish in the excel in front of the row using cells(i, k) k being number of returned search results.
   unfortunately the website did not load for me to help you further

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. Yeah unfortunately the website does occasionally seem to go down I'm not sure why. If for some reason I have made a mistake in my code but you would like to take a look at the website here is the link. https://apps.who.int/food-additives-contaminants-jecfa-database/search.aspx. It its down, it should load again again shortly. This is more of a problem to get into Web Scraping so I will take a look at your resources.